# What is a concrete class in scala?

Tags: scala

Just trying to learns the ins and outs of scala, but I can't find a definition for the term 'concrete class'.  not in the glossary, and the api doc delineate between 'concrete immutable collection classes' and their non immutable counter part, but no mention of what a concrete class is, so what is a concrete class?

Comment: cincrete class is a class, that is not [abstract](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html)

Comment: It hast mostly the same meaning in all languages, TBH.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a type you can instantiate with the "new" keyword (like a Java POJO), then just using the class keyword like so:

```
class MyConcreteClass {

}
```

can be instantiated via:

> val myConcreteClassInstance = new MyConcreteClass

Comment: Please demonstrate (source) that there is another *de jure* (i.e. official) or *de facto* use of "concrete" in the context of Scala classes, other than the one quoted by dk14. Otherwise the answer is a bit misleading in the current form.